# Is there a reason why the "bytes_sent" metric on cloud run containers shows 0 bytes sent?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm trying to make some estimates on the traffic costs of this container that only serves static content.
Container use nginx:latest and serves images and a static html page on port 80.
[metrics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDp9o.png)

The other container APIs with nodejs expose the information correctly.